# I can not parse thru a Nested Json file because Unicode type is returned instead of an Array or List

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get the value of each json elements. I am expecting the type to be an array or list but instead, I get type unicode.

Here's my sample json file:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "account": {
        "basicDetails": {
          "accountId": {
            "acctName": "Test A",
            "acctNumber": "Test B"
          },
          "accountBranchId": {
            "branchName": "Test C",
            "brancNumber": "Test D"
          },
          "cusName": "Test E"
        },
        "otherDetails": {
          "dateCreated": "1999-10-01",
          "dateClosed": "2000-10-01"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "userExtension": {
    "testId": null,
    "version": null
  },
  "status": {
    "overallStatus": "S",
    "messages": null
  },
  "_links": null
}
```

Here is the code I am currently trying

```
def extract_key(self,obj):

    def extract(obj):
        if type(obj)== type(OrderedDict()) or isinstance(obj, list):
            for k, v in obj.items():
                if type(v) == type(OrderedDict()) or type(v)==type(list):
                    extract(v)
                elif type(v) != type(OrderedDict()) or type(v)!=type(list):
                    print(type(k))
                    print(k)
        results = extract(obj)
        return results

def print_keys(self):

    with open("C:\\Account.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

        names = self.extract_key(data)
        return names
```

I'm expecting to get the elements after "accounts": [ but it wont go thru because it treats "accounts" as a unicode instead of a list or array.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked this

```
if type(obj)== type(OrderedDict()) or isinstance(obj, list):
```

and entered into the "accounts", that's ok

Then you've just need:

```
 for k, v in obj.items():

     if obj.items():
              results.append(v)
```

Results got loaded with:

```
[OrderedDict([('account', OrderedDict([('basicDetails', OrderedDict([('accountId', OrderedDict([('acctName', 'Test A'), ('acctNumber', 'Test B')])), ('accountBranchId', OrderedDict([('branchName', 'Test C'), ('brancNumber', 'Test D')])), ('cusName', 'Test E')])), ('otherDetails', OrderedDict([('dateCreated', '1999-10-01'), ('dateClosed', '2000-10-01')]))]))])], OrderedDict([('testId', None), ('version', None)]), OrderedDict([('overallStatus', 'S'), ('messages', None)]), None]
```

Of course results must be declared before that, like:

```
results = []
```